# Navigation Menu (Next, Previous - list item)

Tags: jquery, html, list, css

I need to add Next, Previous buttons and those button should be able to show next list item set, And also this is a responsive design, So the number of items can be different with different resolutions. I feel this is a different method from marquee because of the responsive design. Does any one have a idea to do this ?

[image: It also should be detect and disable next or previous buttons]

`www.jsfiddle.net/3y2Zm`

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: You can use `jQuery` slider plugins. http://jquer.in/best-jquery-plugins-for-beautiful-sliders-2013/barouselthslide/

Comment: @Paulie_D : I'm asking for an idea how to do it, not a code which I can copy and paste on my website. In that case, I guess this is enough to get an idea what was my question.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle to show you how media queries work, but you will probably need to do some research and learn how they work to implement it fully: [http://jsfiddle.net/3y2Zm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/3y2Zm/1/)

Comment: @TheWaxMann : Isn't it a bad idea to limit the number of list items using CSS Media queries? Rather than limiting it, My suggestion was to use jquery and give a next, previous buttons so the user can navigate from the first list item to the last list item. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Using jQuery is a better idea. However, you will need to at least give it a go yourself and show what you have done so far. We are here to help, not write your code for you. This is why you have not got any answers.